# Comprehensive references to learn about the flavor $SU(3)$ model of hadron classification

Tags: particle-physics, resource-recommendations, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics, quarks

What are some comprehensive references to learn about the flavor $SU(3)$ model of hadron classification based on group theory? Textbooks, Lecture notes, videos anything will do. I need to learn this. The books on Particle physics I have, Griffiths, Perkins, etc do not go into much detail.